# Optimize GraphQL Response by Dropping False Fields possible?

Tags: node.js, json, rest, server, graphql

Using a REST API I could replace a response like this:

```
"formatting": {
  "isBold": false,
  "isItalic": true,
  "isUnderlined": false,
  "isFirstWordOfSentence": false
  ... and so on.
},
```

with a response that only returns values when they're true, which could potentially reduce the size of the response significantly:

```
"formatting": {
  "isItalic": true,
},
```

I am wondering if it would be possible to implement something similar in GraphQL?

As far as I know, *GraphQL doesn't allow for empty fields*? Is there a way to reduce the size of the response (the JSON) in this regard? What's usually recommended here for Graphql?

Thanks alot.

Comment: 'custom json type' ?

Comment: what do you mean @xadm ?

Comment: you can use any array/object/struct without defining its internals in schema ... use search/docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A GraphQL response should match the query that produced it. If a field was requested, it should be returned inside the response, always. GraphQL client libraries assume this to be the case, so removing fields with `false` or `null` values can lead to unpredictable bugs in your client application. Even with a REST API, transforming your response like this is generally inadvisable because it makes it harder for the API to be consumed.

If you're concerned about the size of your response, here's some general tips:

- Implement pagination to limit how many elements are returned when resolving a field that returns a List. In the near future, you'll also be able to utilize the `@stream` directive for this purpose.
- Don't expose unnecessary fields in your API and only request the fields that you actually need.
- Enable compression on your HTTP server.